# I want to show a Message to Internet Explorer (10 -11) Only and show it one time a day

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to  show a Message to Internet Explorer (10 -11) Only  and show it once a day

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) || (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1))
{
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    if (!Cookies.get('alreadyShow')) {
    Cookies.set('alreadyShow', true, {
      expires: 1
    });
        $('#ie-note-1').addClass('show');
    }
});
}
```

the message not showing because of the cookie script somehow maybe not working with IE or there is something messing

it always showing 'Cookies' is undefined but i'm adding

```
<script src="http://lab.alexcican.com/set_cookies/cookie.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked your code in a Fiddle and found 2 issues: The Fiddle wasn't able to load the cookie script because the correct URL is https://lab.alexcican.com/set_cookies/cookie.js instead of http://lab.alexcican.com/set_cookies/cookie.js and you're using the cookie functions available in this script wrong. According to https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie the corrected version is

```
 $(window).on('load', function() {
    if (!$.cookie('alreadyShow')) {
       $.cookie('alreadyShow', 'true', {
       expires: 1
       });
       $('#ie-note-1').addClass('show');
    }
 });
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sryvmp2/)

Comment: ERROR is gone but IE is still not showing the message after adding cookie

Comment: @Joeadib I just checked your adjusted script in a local file with IE 11 and it shows the message once as it should be. With which IE version are you checking?

Answer (score 2):

you can use localStorage to store a variable and check it's show today or not.

```
var day = new Date().getDate();
var val = localStorage.getItem("cur_date");
if (!val || val != day) {
   // Show message and update cur_date
   localStorage.setItem("cur_date", day);
}
```

Comment: You are comparing string to number

Comment: I want to show the message just one time per day this code will show the message each time the pager refresh